# extracting text from a pdf with pdftotext

Tags: python, pdf, text, extract, pdftotext

I am trying to extract text from a pdf with python and pdftotext.
I have some weird characters and I don't know what's wrong.
For example, for [this PDF](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cms_data/docs/pressdata/en/jha/70307.pdf) at page 4:
[image: Belgium ...]

It gives me this:
[image: %HOJLXP ...]

There is a problem for "Belgium".
Here is the function I use to get text from a pdf (taken from another SO post):

```
def pdf_to_string(file_object):
    pdfData = file_object.read()

    tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tf.write(pdfData)
    tf.seek(0)

    outputTf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

    if (len(pdfData) > 0) :
        out, err = subprocess.Popen(["pdftotext", "-layout", tf.name, outputTf.name ]).communicate()
        return outputTf.read()
    else :
        return None
```

Should I use another tool?

Comment: It depends a lot on how your PDF was encoded in the first place. From the free softwares I've tested, pdftotext gives the better results (which is not to say they are "good").

Comment: firefox-28.0-3.fc20.x86_64 (with its builtin PDF viewer) does something similar thing when I try to copy & paste that part into gVim. The same happens with evince-3.10.3-1.fc20.x86_64 and 
okular-4.12.4-1.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, this problems happens with all the formatted text: underlined (e.g. from titles), italic or bold. Plain text from regular paragraphs seems to be ok.

Comment: So there might be no solution?

Comment: I think you might be hitting this issue mentioned in the `pdftotext` man page: _Some PDF files contain fonts whose encodings have been mangled beyond recognition.  There is no way (short of OCR) to extract text from these files._ Importing in LibreOffice displayed the same issue so I am afraid you may be out of luck short of using OCR.

Comment: I agree with @PedroRomano. Inspecting the 'mangled' font shows it has a `CharSet` value `(/G3/G11/G12/G13/G15/G16/G17/G18..` (and so on). These names are bound to 'glyphs' with the same name in the embedded Type1C font. Probably the only way to find out what name means what character is to find the original font ("Monotype:Times_New_Roman_Bold:Version_2.50"), convert it to Type 1, and then compare each char string (and I'm not sure that's doable).

Comment: Wow ok, seems complicated. I think I am gonna extract countries manually, then if the problem happens on another document... we'll see :-)

Comment: You probably can use the fact that the encoding for a specific font instance is consistent throughout *this one* document, i.e., for the font "ZUGMGN+Times_New_Roman_Gras0133" you can replace `%` with `B`, `H` with `e` et cetera. Don't assume this encoding is the same for other 'unreadable' fonts though.

Comment: @Jongware, what have you used to inspect the mangled font?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: I wrote my own, using the official specification as guide. It shows a low-level object or page dump, so one still needs to know what all the codes mean.